# Why can't I call this class?

Tags: c#

I have, in the same folder, the class `Home` and `NewsRSS`.
Now, on `Home's PageLoad` method I try to do this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;   

public partial class context_master_MenuPrincipale : System.Web.UI.UserControl 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewsRSS myRss = new NewsRSS();
    }
}
```

this is NewsRSS :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using Chilkat;

public partial class context_NewsRSS : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected string m_strRSS = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BuildRss();
    }

    private void BuildRss()
    {

    }
}
```

I get this error : The type or statement could not be found

Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, A class being in the same folder does not nessesarily determine which namespace it is in. Have you added a using statement?

Comment: post the definition of `NewsRSS()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class is called `context_NewsRSS`, but you're trying to refer to it as `NewsRSS`.

You might be confusing classes and file names or page names, since you say you have a class `Home`, when it's actually `context_master_MenuPrincipale`

Comment: uhm, but with context_NewsRSS myRss = new context_NewsRSS(); nothing change :)

Comment: @markzzz, there must be something else you're not showing us then. :)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Now I get embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement

Comment: You are missing `{}` in the enclosing method/statement.

Comment: You might also need to add `<%@ Reference Control="context_NewsRSS.ascx" %>` (where context_NewsRSS.ascx is mapped path to your control file.

Answer (score 0):

With the additional information:

Your class is named `context_NewsRSS` and you refer to `NewsRSS`. This will not work. Do it this way:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    context_NewsRSS myRss = new context_NewsRSS();
}
```

<strike>Although your question does not provide lots of information, these are the problems I can imagine:</strike>

1. `NewsRSS` is declared `abstract`, which means you cannot create an instance of it directly.
2. `NewsRSS` is declared `internal` in another assembly, which means you cannot use it anywhere but in the declaring assembly or assemblies that can see the internal types of the declaring assembly (controlled by [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) in the declaring assembly).
3. `NewsRSS` is declared in another namespace that is not referenced via the `using` keyword in the file your code is located in.

Comment: I get : embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement